# Как зависать ответ сервера в DOM

Tags: json, promise

Подскажите, как ответ data записать в `<main>`

```js
   let main = document.querySelector(".main");

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data)
        .then( data => console.log("!!!", data))
        .catch(() => console.log('some error...'));


   includeInformation  = () => {
        main.innerHTML='<p>data</p>';
    };
    includeInformation();
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: А в каком формате Вы его хотите записывать? Ведь `data` это массив с объектами, не совсем понятно, что Вам нужно.

Comment: пока просто в переменную забрать этот массив и вывести в main. Потом я попробую его разложить. Это тренировочный таск

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => includeInformation(data))
  .catch(() => console.log('some error...'));

includeInformation = (data) => {
  const main = document.querySelector(".main");
  main.innerHTML = data.map(e => `<div><h3>${e.title}</h3><p>${e.body}</p></div><hr>`).join('');
};
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в строке `.then(data => includeInformation(data))` мы в качестве переменной для функции передаем значение которое вернуло сервер ?

Comment: @AndreyZirka, да